# Mistake in DS 160 realised after visa issuance

Tags: visas, usa

I recently completed a visa interview. However afterwards I realised that I had made a nonmaterial mistake on the ds-160. How can this be corrected?

Comment: What was the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot correct an already submitted DS-160 unless it’s denied for incorrect/incomplete answers and [reopened by the consulate.](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/forms/ds-160-online-nonimmigrant-visa-application/ds-160-faqs.html)

However, assuming it’s before your interview, you can [generally submit a new DS-160 including the corrected information](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/made-mistake-form-ds-160-i-fix-after-submitted.html#:%7E:text=Although%20it%27s%20true%20that%20the,at%20the%20consulate%20or%20embassy.), and bring that confirmation to the interview appointment.

If you’ve already completed an interview/been issued a visa then it look likely depend on the specifics of the mistake. I.e. is it something that came up properly in the interview, and the DS-160 just had a simple typo, in which case I can’t imagine it matters at this point. Or is it something that looks like you hid something in which case it’s likely more problematic.